# Nodal planes in a molecular orbital

Tags: bond

How are nodes in a molecular orbital different different from those of atomic orbitals?

eg. For a Px-Px Pi bond, we would say that the nodal plane is the Y-Z plane (correct me). How about for a Pi* (antibonding) molecular orbital?

I think it should be similar to an atomic orbital, but please confirm.

Comment: The nodal planes in a $\pi^*$ orbital are analogous to the nodal planes in a $d_{xy}$ atomic orbital. Note the plural.

Comment: Why is that? Can you explain more?

Comment: They are not. A nodal plane is just a plane where the electrons’ wave function is zero. There is no distinction between ‘two types of zero’.

Comment: I see, so nodal planes are similarly defined as areas where probability of finding an electron is 0? That means nodal planes for all 3 cases - p-p atomic, p-p pi and p-p pi* will be same, right?